# Clash of clans Tiebreaker

Tags: clash-of-clans

With the new Tiebreaker where it says best attacks total destruction, the best attacks wording is what confuses me as the best attacks would be 100%.... so how would that break the tie?

Comment: Its the average of the best attack (% wise) on each base

Answer (score 4):

The best attack is not always, but in fact rarely a 3 star, or 100%. I have yet to find solid proof to confirm or debunk, but in theory, the best attack is based on destruction, stars, level of attacker, level of defender ((town hall included)), as well as time used, clan castle troops killed, and remaining heroes.

For example, if a town hall 10 pulverized another town hall 10 with 3 stars, but a town hall 8 2 starred the same, or a more difficult town hall 10, the town hall 8 would get the best attack.

Lets say that town hall 8 got a 76% destruction total. Keep that in mind.

Now let's also say your enemy clan got a 75% on their best attack. Keep that in mind as well.

At the end if the war, both clans are tied at 84 stars. Previously it would be a draw. But with this update, now your clan would win since your best attack got 1% more destruction than the enemy did.

Now let's say you both got 74%. As of this update, that would still be a draw, as happened [here](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/845492-Probably-the-FIRST-DRAW-with-the-new-Clan-Wars-Update).

Answer (score 0):

I believe they mean it is the sum of the total %'s of the best attacks on all bases. If 1 attack resulted in 51% destruction, and a later one ended up at 75% destruction, the 75% would be added to that team's total destruction amount.

Answer (score -2):

It would most likely tie, maybe it would give the victory to the team with less attacks.

I think the previous answer is quite wrong in a lot of places. 
The best attack will always remain a 3 star perfect attack despite of who attacked what.

Say in a 10 Person war a tie for 30/30 100% destruction is very plausible. 
Thus I'm sure it would either still be a draw or at least it would come down to a different factor to break the tie.. which would probably be # of attacks or perhaps another stat.

The link he shared showed a 15 person clan war ending up with the exact same % and stars [29 is pretty low for a 15 person clanwar considering there are 45 possible stars]. So that was a strong coincidence but hardly proving anything he said. As clan wars get bigger the possibility of a tie is further out of reach. Due to the unlikelihood of people getting the same or matching %s on their attacks that are not 3 star attacks.